# mysql driver eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jdbc

Hi this question has been asked several times and I searched all of them but everything is in vain. I have a simple JDBC program running in Eclipse as a Java application. I put MySQL connector in the build path. But it shows `driver not found`. I have searched two whole days on the internet. Everybody says it's a  problem with build path. I'm sure 1000 times it is a problem with the build path.

Using Eclipse Juno, MySQL connector 5.1 (I also tried 5.0). But all these efforts have been in vain.

Comment: Show us the code. How are you loading the driver?

Answer (score 0):

The procedure listed below was done from scratch, so it should work for you.

1. Create a Java Project.
2. Add a file to the project, say, 'JDBCexample'.
3. Add this code:

   ```
   import java.io.*;

   //STEP 1. Import required packages
   import java.sql.*;

   public class JDBCexample {
      // JDBC driver name and database URL
      static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
      static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

      //  Database credentials
      static final String USER = "user1";
      static final String PASS = "user1";

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Connection conn = null;
      Statement stmt = null;
      try{
         //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

         //STEP 3: Open a connection
         System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

         //STEP 4: Execute a query
         System.out.println("Creating statement...");
         stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql;
         sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

         //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
         while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            int id  = rs.getInt("id");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String first = rs.getString("first");
            String last = rs.getString("last");

            //Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
            System.out.print(", First: " + first);
            System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
         }
         //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
         rs.close();
         stmt.close();
         conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         //finally block used to close resources
         try{
            if(stmt!=null)
               stmt.close();
         }catch(SQLException se2){
         }// nothing we can do
         try{
            if(conn!=null)
               conn.close();
         }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
         }//end finally try
      }//end try
      System.out.println("Goodbye!");
   }//end main
   }//end FirstExample
   ```
4. Download [this](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412052) file.
5. Extract the file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar" and add it to your project's build path. (right-click --> build-path --> configure build-path --> Libraries --> Add external JARs).
6. Create appropriate tables. Below is what I used:
   Schema name is 'emp'.
   Table name is 'employees'.
   [image]
7. Build the project and Run it.

You should be able to get the results like this:

```
    Connecting to database...
    Creating statement...
    ID: 100, Age: 18, First: Zara, Last: Ali
    ID: 101, Age: 25, First: Mahnaz, Last: Fatma
    ID: 102, Age: 30, First: Zaid, Last: Khan
    ID: 103, Age: 28, First: Sumit, Last: Mittal
    Goodbye!
```

Try using this as a template for your own code if you please. If you face any problems, please do post it below.